# Notepad++ regex get 2nd group

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a tex with 32k lines like this example

```
A01.2 Some Text
A01.3 some Text
A01.4 3Some Text
A02.0 [some text]
B02.1 Text .05 example
```

I need to replace white spaces with ';' symbol.

I tried `(\S{3}\.\d)(\s)` but notepad++ highlights/gets both groups`B02.1` with whitespace.

1st question: how do i disable 1st group, or take only 2nd
2nd question: is there another expression do find only this white space?

Here is the [real](https://regex101.com/r/gB5aS0/3) example:

Comment: I'm confused - what is your desired output? `B02.1;Text;.05;example`?

Comment: I guess you only need to match the space after `A01.2`, `B02.1`.... that are always at the beginning of the line?

Comment: I think one of the safest is `^[A-Z0-9.]+\K\s+`, or `^[A-Z0-9]+\.\d+\K\s+`.

Comment: @eminach: Did you have time to check the posted suggestions? Please let us know.  I do not want to post my answer if there is one that is valid and working for you.

Comment: Thanks all, 1. @albcif post helped, 2 @Andrea's `(?<=\S{3}\.\d)(\s)` expression works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace the whitespace by `;`, so this `B02.1` will be `B02.1;` using notepad++; since you're capturing the groups then use `$` notation in the replace expression.

Find: `(\S{3}\.\d)(\s)`
Replace: `$1;`

`$1` is for the first captured group.

Hope it helps,

[image]

Comment: @eminach nice to help you `:)`

Answer (score 1):

1. You disable the first group simply not grouping it:

   ```
   \S{3}\.\d(\s)
   ```

Otherwise, the look-behind may suite your case:

```
(?<=\S{3}\.\d)(\s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a lookbehind so `B02.1` won't get matched:

```
(?<=\S{3}\.\d)(\s)
```